# QBXML SalesOrderAdd issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

I am trying to create SalesOrder through QBWebConnector (backend - Rails + [qbwc](https://github.com/qbwc/qbwc)), following [Onscreen Reference for Intuit Software Development Kits](https://static.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/common/newosr/index.html), and it says that `SalesOrderAdd` requires only `CustomerRef` attribute, but QBXML validator says:

```
Line: 10
LinePos: 9
Src Text: </SalesOrderAdd>
Reason: Element content is incomplete according to the DTD/Schema.
Expecting: ClassRef, TemplateRef, TxnDate, RefNumber, BillAddress, ShipAddress, PONumber, TermsRef, DueDate, SalesRepRef, FOB, ShipDate.
```

QBXML Request is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <SalesOrderAddRq>
      <SalesOrderAdd>
        <CustomerRef>
          <FullName>Test customer</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
      </SalesOrderAdd>
    </SalesOrderAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Why is that? Can I change this behavior somehow (omit all tags except pointed as required in Onscreen Reference)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSR is... less than perfect. But it *does* indicate there are additional required fields.

You need to add at least one line item or group line.

[image]